# Defining Order of AutoConfigure not working

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an example project [here](https://github.com/ndrone/stackoverflow/tree/master/48853995/ordersystem). In this multi module project. I have module `promotion-service` on which the `PromotionConfiguration` relies on other configurations to be completed first.

`@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter({RulesConfiguration.class, PointsConfiguration.class})
public class PromotionConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    public PromotionService promotionService(ObjectProvider<List<Rule>> rules)
    {
        System.out.println("Adding PromotionService to context");
        List<Rule> ruleList = rules.getIfAvailable();
        if (!ruleList.isEmpty())
        {
            ruleList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Rule::getOrder));
        }
        return new PromotionServiceImpl(ruleList);
    }
}`

But when the spring boot application that has a dependency of module `promotion-service` the rules are added to the context after the promotion-service is

`2018-02-18 11:20:26.743  INFO 11582 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
Adding PromotionService to context
Adding PointRule to context.
Adding PromotionRule to context.
2018-02-18 11:20:27.087  INFO 11582 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@196a42c3: startup date [Sun Feb 18 11:20:25 EST 2018]; root of context hierarchy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between parsing the configuration and its structure and effectively creating beans at runtime. What is the concrete problem here?

If I run your project, the `promotionService` is created with 2 rules as you'd expect. If I add `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(Rule.class)` on `promotionService` it is not created (which proves the context knows that at least one `Rule` bean is going to be created).

You shouldn't worry too much about the runtime part, the context is free to invoke the necessary factory methods (i.e. `@Bean` annotated methods) according to its optimized plan (it namely does smart stuff to resolve cycles).

The reason why you get this log output is that you're not asking the context to resolve the `Rule` beans. `ObjectProvider` is a proxy that won't do anything until you ask for something (`getAvailable` in this case).

I've changed the injection point to use `List<Rule>` and I got the following:

```
Adding PointRule to context.
Adding PromotionRule to context.
Adding PromotionService to context
```

So all is good. But please, rename your auto-configuration so that they ends with `AutoConfiguration` rather than `Configuration`.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I needed the context resolved because of the sorting before passing it to the `PromotionService` implementation

Comment: That's not how it works Nicholas. You don't need to order the bean definitions parsing to get that result. Standard injection mechanism is enough to teach the context how to create/load things. The order is important for conditions evaluation.

Comment: Yes sorry order isn't important to spring. But for when my code get executed it is important at runtime for the correct rule to be ran first.

Comment: That's what I am saying. You don't need ordering rules for that as long as your configuration structure is sensible. The `ApplicationContext` figures this out itself (though it's obviously better to give it the proper hint.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help